# Cannot run Whenever task with sudo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, delayed-job, whenever

I want to execute a task with whenever rails gem at every reboot like this

```
every :reboot do 
   script "cd :path && RAILS_ENV=:environment && rvmsudo ruby script/delayed_job start :environment"
end
```

however rvmsudo will prompt for the password
what could be a workaround to successfully execute the task?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sudo remembers your password for 5 minutes by default. And, rvmsudo simply calls sudo so it too remembers your password.

```
every :reboot do
    #hack to rvmsudo to use password later 
    sudo "your_password"
    script "cd :path && RAILS_ENV=:environment && rvmsudo ruby script/delayed_job start    :environment"
end
```

Comment: sorry, quite new to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Actually to run sudo command in one line I have found this,  
`echo <<password>> | sudo -S <<command>>`
then I can proceed with the rest